# Success callback not executed in angular HTTPClient subscribe

Tags: angular, callback, observable, angular-httpclient

I currently have an angular project, that makes a request to the server, however, the success callback specified inside `createBatch` is never executed.

I don't seem to spot where this error is coming from, any pointer or solution would be appreciated.

```
// Template

 <arms-loader-indicator *ngIf='isLoading'></arms-loader-indicator>
 <div class='signup-form'>
    <label for='file'>Select a file: </label>
    <input
    type='file'
    name='students'
    (change) = 'checkValidity($event)'
    id='file'
    #students
    accept='application/octet-stream,application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'>
    <button type='button' [disabled]='validForm' type='submit' (click) = createBatch(students.files[0]) class='btn btn-secondary'>Submit</button>
  </div>



 // Method called on button click

 createBatch(file): void {
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('students', file);
 this.msgService.hideMessage();
 this.isLoading = true;
 this.studentService.createStudentByBatch(formData).subscribe(
  (data) => {
     console.log('data: ', data); // This code is never executed even when he server return 200 status
     if (data.status === 200) {
       this.isLoading = false;
       this.msgService.showMessage('success', 'students uploaded successfully', 5000);
     }
   },
   error => {
     if (error.status === 422) {
       this.isLoading = false;
       this.msgService.showMessage('error', 'Unable to upload, student(s) already exists', 10000);
     }
   }
 );
}


// Student's createStudentByBatch service method

 createStudentByBatch(payload) {
 let token = this.auth.getToken('admin');
 return this.http.post(`${this.auth.BASE_URL}${this.BASE}/student/upload`, payload, {
   observe: 'response',
   headers: {
     Authorization: token
   }
 })
}


 // Current route defination

 const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: views.SigninFormComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'signup',
   component: views.SignupFormComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'send/email',
   component: views.AdminEmailSendComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'password/reset',
   component: views.PasswordResetComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'dashboard',
   component: views.AdminComponent,
   canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
   children: [
     {
       path: '',
       component: component.DashBoardHighlightsComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'student/create',
       component: views.StudentCreateComponent
     }
    ]
  }
];
```

Images showing network response

[image]

[image]

Image showing an empty console output

[image]

Version information

```
 Angular CLI: 9.1.3
 Node: 12.16.1
 OS: win32 x64
```

Comment: what's your server-side response/code to that http request?

Comment: Server side response code is 200

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because your header options for the http post request are wrong. I don't know what the purpose of the `observe` parameter is, but it appears it only takes a single string value of `body`.

Secondly, that's not how you would set your HttpHeaders. This is what I would do:

```
const body = JSON.stringify(payload);
const requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token});
return this.http.post(environment.API_ENDPOINT, body, {headers: requestHeaders});
```

Do some checks whether your server-side code actually processed your request correctly, and is returning data you expect it to.

Documentation on adding headers: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers